# Axis 2 - Is it possible to test operations through the web interface?

Tags: java, apache-axis

Short version of my quesiton: 
Is it possible to test a web service via the web page provided by the Axis 2 web application?

More detail: In the web page provided by Axis 2 (the one where all of your services are listed and you can view WSDLs and administer Axis 2), is there somewhere you can test operations for your service by entering input parameters and viewing the XML responses that are returned? In .NET, you can do this on .asmx pages that list all available operations and allow you to input parameters and view XML responses. However, in Axis 2, all I really see is the services listed, and clicking on them allows you to view the WSDL, but besides that, I don't see any functionality that would allow you to test right on the page. It would really just be convenient.

Ex. I have a service that lets me input product numbers (as POST parameters) and returns details of those products. Is there a way I can select the operation, enter the post data, post it, and view the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides using soapUI, as Andreas_D suggested, you can also use Eclipse to test the web service by calling it with request data and see its response.

Eclipse EE comes with a tool called Web Service Explorer which you can [use to test a Web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/WebServiceExplorer.html).

Given access to the WSDL of the service, it creates a simple GUI to call all operations of the web service and also presents the result of the call. The `source` link in the GUI also allows you to view the SOAP source directly.

The web page provided by the Axis 2 web application only gives you details of the web service, its not meant for testing it with sample data.

Comment: Thank you dpb. I've used Web Service Explorer before as well, although I don't like it quite as much has soapUI. I think you and Andreas_D both answered my question ... which is that the Axis 2 web app is not intended for and does not support functional testing for services. I think your answer provides a little more detail and a definite answer, so I'm going to mark this as the correct answer as it will most likely be more helpful to anyone viewing this in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For webservice testing - you mention axis2, so I guess you talk about SOAP based services - I usually rely on [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

In addition, I don't think that the [axis 2 web admin app](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_0/webadminguide.html) is intended to support functional webservice testing.

Comment: I was just thinking it seems odd that they don't have a test harness right in the app itself. It would just be much more convenient than using a third party tool.

Comment: So as far as you know, they definitely don't have a way to do it in the application?

Comment: Thanks for the soapUI tip by the way ... it works really nicely.